# Mouse cursor flicker on Dual Monitor set up

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, cursor

Im a pretty casual user coming over from Windows and I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is going great, and I'm excited to learn my way around linux.

However I have encountered one problem i just can't seem to solve, my cursor flickers when in use, and disappears when i left click or when it's inactive. It also disappears completely when on top of open windows.

I did see similar questions like this asked and solved, but most of those pertain to only one monitor, where the solution is to disable an "unknown monitor" however i have two monitors and that solution doesn't work for me.

Another solution was to install my proprietary drivers for my Nvidia card, so I did, and it did solve the issue, however i lose my second monitor, since it is not connected to the graphics card directly only my main monitor is.

So i am wondering if there is a way to keep both of my monitors since they are essential to my workflow, and fix the cursor flicker issue.

GPU:GTX 770

CPU:i5 4430

Main monitor:Samsung 1440x900

Second monitor: ViewSonic 1440x900

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Linux! Quick questions, do you see the other monitor in nvidia-settings or in the display manager?

Comment: Thank you! No, not with the proprietary drivers installed.